# Image matching and object detection, how to perform detection for small object?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, object-detection, object-recognition

I am using SIFT feature the matching between two images or it can be considered as object detection.

**First matching**. I used SIFT feature for matching and it failed when the object is small.

**Second matching**. However, it woks when I cropped that object out from that image.

Any suggestions or ideas to improve the first matching without cropping?

Example images are shown below.

**Image A**: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/21827/imageA.png

**Image B**: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/21828/imageB.png

**Image C** cropped out from image B: mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/21829/imageC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the standard approach is to do sliding window detection, i.e start with a window size, slide it over the image and take the window (at some position x,y) which matches best, this thing can be done with windows of multiple sizes.

Comment: window size based matching is useful, but the speed is quite slow

Comment: here is a way to do it faster, http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/pdfs/pdf5070.pdf